# Depth frame acquisition with Openni + Qt + Asus Xtion Pro Live

Tags: c++, qt, openni, 3dcamera

For several days now, I encounter a problem regarding depth frame acquisition with my Asus Xtion Pro Live, Openni 2 and Qt. My application works fine when the camera is connected to a USB 2.0 port, but when I try to connect the camera to a USB 3.0 port, I cannot display images from the depth stream.

I wrote a very basic console application in order to solve the problem, that just acquire color and depth frames and for each frame, write the timestamp and the index in a file. It appears that the number of depth frames received become very small compared to color frames (1784 color frames against 464 depth frames, for an acquisition of 1 mn). Connecting the camera to USB 2.0 port, I get well 1784 color frames and 1784 depth frames.

I noticed that using QApplication instead of a QCoreApplication, the number of depth frame images decrease in number (44 depth frames for an acquisition of 1 mn).

Do you think that the problem come from Qt or from the camera and its drivers ? I red on Asus support that there were some problems with Asus Xtion Pro live and USB 3.0. I downloaded a patch from http://reconstructme.net/2012/10/13/asus-xtion-usb-3-0-hotfix-2/ but it doesn't correct my problem.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Last week, i decided to take my courage in both hands and tried to solve my problem regarding my Asus Xtion Pro Live and Qt. I am sorry to resurrect this topic, but i have recently come across a website that solves my problem http://www.qimaging.com/support/chipset.php. As they say, the problem comes from the USB controller :

"*Intel released a new version of their mother board chipsets (Series 7/C216, Series 8/C220 and later) with a native Intel based USB 3.0 host controller (USB3 extensible host controller, xHCI in the Device Manager). On these newer PCs, the Intel USB 3.0 host controller does not communicate properly with some traditional USB 2.0 chipsets to the extent where data is not properly delivered*"

I followed their advice and bought a StarTech 2 Port PCI Express Card Adapter and now i can acquire depth stream and color stream from camera without any problem.